# Writing through UART to a microcontroller

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial, uart

I am new to python. I  am using a BeagleBone Black Wireless, with Debian 9.5 installed on it as well as Python 3.5.3
The Microcontroller is connected to my BeagleBone via USB. It is reading the serial line at baud rate 9600. I can control solenoids to turn on or off by sending enable "9----" to the microcontroller, where - can be a 0 or a 1.
to turn on solenoid 1 and 3 I would have to send '91010'
to turn all of them off I would have to send '90000'

I need a python program that would help me send enable signals (9----)

I am using this from PYserial documentation as my reference:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600, timeout = 0)  # open serial port
print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used
ser.write(str('91010'))     # write a string
line = ser.readline()
ser.close()             # close port
```

If I run this program, theoretically, would that work to turn solenoid 1 and 3 on? Ideally, I would like to create a function with 4 arguments, one for the state of each solenoid , for example something like pwr_solenoid(1,1,1,1) would send '91111' over serial to turn all the solenoids on

Comment: Did you run your program?

Comment: No, on my microcontroller , the application that runs the program that would turn the solenoids on is not ready yet , so I am unable to test this program. I have also ordered an FTDI cable for debugging but I have not received it yet. If there is anything you think needs to be changed/added please point that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the data as `bytes` e.g.
 `'91010'.encode()` using
https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write

Also if the serial port has a way for it to tell you if the write operation is successful, you can also do `ser.read` after you write using https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read and process that output

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So for the first one, would it be : ser.write('91010'.encode('utf-8')) instead of just ser.write('91010') ?
For the second one , should I just add ser.read after the line where I use write?

Comment: Yes that is how you should format your write, and assuming your read actually replies, you need to specify how many bytes you want to read as well

Comment: I just noticed that they for python versions after 2.5 it accepts byte, bytearray and str. Shouldn't str be fine then?

Comment: I don't understand what I need to read in this task and what you mean by if my read actually replies, could you please explain? I do have another task that requires reading but I don't think I have mentioned that in my post

Comment: Sometimes when you write on a serial port, it also will respond with a message saying if the write is successful, that message can be processed via read function, not sure if the serial port you are using provides that function or not

Comment: I guess it wouldn't harm to have it there, thanks. Right now I am trying to create a function that accepts 4 arguments for each solenoid respectively so I can turn any combination on or off and send over uart with one function call

Comment: Great, let me know if you have any more questions, if the answer helped you please upvote/accept it

Comment: Hi @NeilNabilIlSaidawi :) Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you :), and please also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers